# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. if the transferring string size is more than 48KB

Tags: wcf

i have a self hosted wcf service, below are the config details of both service and client, it works fine if the transferred string/data size is less than 48KB but if the size is more then it throws the title error.
i am new to wcf and searched this issue, found many earlier reports which ask to configure the buffer size but its not working in my case.
Thanks.

**Server config details**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_DeployConfiguration" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="CPConfigDeploy.DeployConfiguration">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="CPConfigDeploy.IDeployConfiguration"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**and below is the client config details**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DeployConfiguration" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836480" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836480" maxBufferSize="10485760" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.140.188.117:8080/deploy" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_DeployConfiguration"
        contract="IDeployConfiguration" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDeployConfiguration"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign the binding configuration you defined to the service endpoint.  In your service's config you have:

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="CPConfigDeploy.IDeployConfiguration"/>
```

Since there's no `bindingConfiguration` value set, the system uses the default values for `basicHttpBinding`.

What you need is this:

```
 <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_DeployConfiguration"
          contract="CPConfigDeploy.IDeployConfiguration"/>
```

Then your service will pick up the larger values you specified for the binding configuration.